# Certificate Exception running maven verify command using Java 1.8

Tags: java, maven, ssl, intellij-idea

My JUnit test class works fine when I run it with IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). But when I try to run it with the Maven command it fails for the below exception. The Maven command is below:

```
mvn clean verify -Dapp-env=dev
```

Note : I am trying to connect to Kafka with TLS enabled and the `ca-cert.pem` is already added to the JDK (inside JRE).

Exception:

```
2020-04-03 12:18:21 [pool-1-thread-5] ERROR n.t.c.steps.ConsoleLoggingListener - PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2020-04-03 12:18:23 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Metadata update failed due to authentication error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Do you use the same JDK in IntelliJ IDEA and the command line? Double check the CA is added to all the JVMs you are using. http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ is a handy tool to verify your keystores.

Comment: Yes there is only one Java version installed on the system. It says the same Java version  when i check from the command line and from the IDE.

Comment: You can run with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` VM option from IntelliJ IDEA and from the command line, then compare the output to find out what's the difference and which specific CA is not found. It's possible that your command line tests override the keystore via another VM option.